(SDK issues) Google Play Core (com.google.android.play:core) has added this note for SDK version 1.10.3:
Recenlty in my last 2 versions on the google play i had this message. I know it says to look the migration guide but then i got these errors:
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.play:asset-delivery:2.2.2
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.play:asset-delivery-ktx:2.2.2
Failed to resolve: com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0
etc...

I use the "com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3"

Follow the following migration guide https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration but first remove from your gradle files the following line: com.google.android.play:core

The warning message indicates that the PlayCore SDK (com.google.android.play:core) is outdated and core library has split into Four(Play Feature Delivery Library, Play In-App Reviews Library, Play Assets Delivery Library and Play In-App Updates Library) parts. Your App may crash if your app targets SDK 34+ (targetSdkVersion). To resolve this issue, here are the simple steps->
Delete the following dependencies(whichever applicable) from build.grade (Module :app)->
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'

As the Core Library is divided into 04 parts so as per your App's requirement you need to add specific dependency (Link for dependencies).
After adding dependencies just Sync Project with  Gradle Files.
on Last replace

import com.google.android.play.core.tasks.*

with

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.*

in import statement in Activity.

In my case, The issue is little different. I have not used the com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library in my project. But Play Store show the error message as

Update your com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 Maven dependency to an
Android 14 compatible version! Your current
com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library is incompatible with
targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a
backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers. As a reminder,
from August 31, 2024, Google Play requires all new app releases to
target Android 14. Update to the latest library version dependency to
avoid app crashes.

I spend 4 hours time to find the issue but tired. Finally, I have a hunch,
I went to File -> Project Structure
On Project Structure screen, I have found the library used in other libraries.
Example: (for example I am showing a library, but the finding & solution applicable to any other library)
Just consider to find the usage of "androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0". At build.gradle or build.gradle.kts file, I have not used this library.
But on Project Structure screen:

The androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0 library used inside the com.google.android.material:material:1.12.0 library.
Same format I followed for com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3 library also. So what are other core libraries used com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3, I removed those libraries and updated relevant new library.
So first and foremost thing is find the usage of the library.

So, did you use com.google.android.material:material:1.13.0-alpha05 instead?

Hi @doctorram, Just for example I mentioned this library. I faced issue in different library.

Problem Statement:
The Play Core Java and Kotlin Library has been partitioned into multiple per-feature Android libraries. That's why google shows warning or sdk issue messages into console account or throws error into terminal.
Solution:
Remove any imports of the old Play Core libraries in your build.gradle file.
Scenario:
In my case i was using this "In-App-Update" (https://github.com/prongbang/inapp-update) old library which includes
dependencies {
    api 'com.google.android.play:core-ktx:1.8.1'
}

Later i'd to remove that library and added these libraries, here's the final look of my apps build.gradle.kts file.
    dependencies {
        //implementation("com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3")
        //implementation("com.github.prongbang:inapp-update:1.0.1")

        // This dependency is downloaded from the Google’s Maven repository.
        // Make sure you also include that repository in your project's build.gradle file.
        implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0")
    
        // For Kotlin users, also import the Kotlin extensions library for Play In-App Update:
        implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0")
    }

And my settings.gradle.kts file look like this:
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

If still facing same issue then you have to migrate your current project groovy to kotlin dsl gradle first (https://medium.com/@nicosnicolaou/migration-from-groovy-to-kotlin-dsl-gradle-part-1-c065fe19fcb4)
Happy conding :)

The google play core library version you are using has been released in January of 2022.
Because of that, it does not comply with new Android OS versions.
In this link, Google announced (in April 2022), that the core library has been split and has a suggested migration guide for this (can be found here).
EDIT
I wrote an article explaining how to perform the migration that can be found here.

I also got  following msg
Update your Play Core Maven dependency to an Android 14 compatible version! Your current Play Core library is incompatible with targetSdkVersion 34 (Android 14), which introduces a backwards-incompatible change to broadcast receivers to improve user security. As a reminder, from August 31, Google Play requires all new app releases to target Android 14.
You may not be able to release future versions of your app with this SDK version to production or open testing.
I am using 1.10.0 version, so am I able to release the new version on play store with 1.10.0

@Salmankhan - As mentioned in the answer, you too need to migrate to the new core library.

Probably if i understand this well, we have to remove core library and add these 4 (or what you are use) from this link in order to be compatible with android 14 https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

@PanosMakris - That is correct. If my answer helped you, please mark it as such so others can find it more easily.

(Step1)
Add these three dependencies in your build.gradle(app) file
   implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.2'

and remove your core dependency which is causing issue.....
(Step2)
update your relevant code according to the above dependencies.
Add this below import where you have relevant code in the acitvity
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

